# Вызов метода класса в JS

Tags: ооп, extjs, javascript

Уже мягко говоря задолбал этот ExtJS. Я не могу понять системы работы классов. Проблема: имеется класс App, имеющий метод ShowTaskBar() и HideTaskBar(). Сейчас панель спрятана и в обработчике нажатия кнопки Login() я пытаюсь вызвать ShowTaskBar(). 2 часа убил на отладку ошибки "this.ShowTaskBar is not a function" пока не понял, что this там не класс App, а класс кнопки, в котором в свойстве handler: thisObect.Login

```
Ext.extend(Ext.app.App, Ext.util.Observable, 
{
  ...
  taskBar: null,
  ...
  HideTaskBar : function()
  {
      this.taskBar.hide();
  },
  ShowTaskBar : function()
  {
      this.taskBar.show();
  },
  ...
  StartLoginWindow: function()
  {
      this.HideTaskBar(); //можно и через this        
      var thisObject = this; //чтоб увидеть текущий класс App далее
      this.login_window = new Ext.Window
      ({
      ...
      items:  [{
                  buttons: 
                  [{
                     text: 'Войти',
                     id: 'submit-login-button',
                     handler: thisObject.Login //обработчик, Login вызывает App
                  }]
      ....
  },
  Login: function()
  {
      var thisObject = this; //this уже объект button!!
      //надо достучаться до App!
  }
}
```

Вот как в том месте достучаться до класса App? Какая странная система описания классов в JavaScript. Как будто я не обработчик указываю как вызов метода класса App, а просто указываю код, который выполнится на месте вызова (как будто функция Login копируется в handler: и выполняется и к классу App, в котором описана, отношения не имеет). Просвятите пожалуйста.

Почему thisObject.Login вызывает метод и при этом this в нем не содержимое thisObject, а button. Конструкция handler: thisObject.Login просто вызывает функцию (методом уже не посмею назвать, ибо он ничейный) Login? Но никак не App::Login() ?

Comment: У вас:
`this.login_window = new Ext.Window
      ({...
`
тут `(` вы потом `)` не забыли кстати?

Comment: @Rules, нет. В коде просто этот класс очень большой и я его урезал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Ext.extend(Ext.app.App, Ext.util.Observable, 
{
  ...
  taskBar: null,
  ...
  HideTaskBar : function()
  {
      this.taskBar.hide();
  },
  ShowTaskBar : function()
  {
      this.taskBar.show();
  },
  ...
  StartLoginWindow: function()
  {
      this.HideTaskBar(); //можно и через this        
      var thisObject = this; //чтоб увидеть текущий класс App далее
      this.login_window = new Ext.Window
      ({
      ...
      items:  [{
                  buttons: 
                  [{
                     text: 'Войти',
                     id: 'submit-login-button',
                     handler: function(){
                         thisObject.Login(thisObject);
                     }
                  }]
      ....
  },
  Login: function(obj)
  {
      var thisObject = obj; //так должно работать
      //надо достучаться до App!
  }
}
```

Comment: @ilyas, спасибо Вам добрый человек) Я пробовал передать параметром (handler: thisObject.Login(thisObject)), но не додумался обернуть это в функцию. Это приводило просто к вызову. Уже думал тело функции Login переписывать в handler)) Спасибо еще раз)